# アプリで作成したファイルをデバイスやPCから見られる場所に保存するには

Tags: android, eclipse

androidのアプリで作成したファイル(主に.csv)を、任意のフォルダに保存することは可能でしょうか。

getFilesDir()では/data/user/0/<パッケージ名>/files、
getExternalStorageDirectory()では/storage/emulated/0、
getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(directory)では/storage/emulated/0/directoryにそれぞれ保存されるらしく、どれもデバイスからもPCからも見れないフォルダになっています。
これを特別な操作(adbコマンド)などを使用せずに、保存先を触れる場所に指定することは可能でしょうか。
ちなみにeclipseでAndroid6.0を使っています。

パーミッションはmanifest.xmlにきちんと明記してあります。
作成したファイルをすぐにPCに移して作業することを目指しています。
プログラミング初心者なので、説明が足りないかもしれませんがよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

まず前提として、Androidでは任意のディレクトリに保存できません。
ご提示のとおりにgetExternalStoragePublicDirectory()等のアプリの権限で許可されたディレクトリにしか保存出来ません。

本題に戻しまして
getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()で取得されたディレクトリは、マスストレージとしてアクセス出来るディレクトリのはずです。

例えばgetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)に保存した場合を例にします。
1. AndroidデバイスとPCをUSBでつなぐ
2. Notificationに「この端末をUSB充電」という通知が出ているはずなのでコレをタップ
3. 選択肢がいくつか出ているはずなので「ファイルを転送する」をタップ
4. PC側のエクスプローラー等でデバイスのストレージが見えているはずなので内部共有ストレージへアクセス
5. Downloadディレクトリに目的のファイルが保存されているはず

(2.3.の手順は昔のAndroid Versionでは不要でいきなりつながるはずです。どのVersionからだったかはすぐに出てきませんが6.0であれば必要手順のはずです。)

上記手順を行なっても保存されたファイルが見えない場合はMediaScanが更新されていないものと思います。
ファイルは保存されているがファイルシステムが更新されていないので見えない、と言った状態です。
更新するには以下のいずれかで
・Androidをデバイス再起動
・保存後以下のコードを組み込みメディアスキャンを要求する

```
Uri uri =Uri.parse("file://" + RESULT_DIR+"/"+RESULT_FILE);//RESULT_DIR/FILEは保存対象のパス
//mediascan
sendBroadcast(new Intent(
    Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, uri));
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.D‌​IRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)で‌​試してみたところ、内部ストレージの/st‌​orage/emulatedまでは見れた‌​のですが、その中には0という拡張子も何も‌​ないファイルがあるのみでDownload‌​というフォルダにはいけませんでした。頂い‌​たMediaScanのコードは、どこに 書けばよいのでしょうか。ファイルを書き込むメソッドの中で書けば良いですか

Comment: その「0」というのはファイルではなくディレクトリのはずで、その下にDownloadディレクトリ等があるはずです。ただWindowsエクスプローラー上でアクセスしているのならば、/storage/emulated/0/は意識しないはずなのですが、どのようにアクセスしてらっしゃいますでしょうか？またコードの入れる位置につきましては、ファイル保存が終わったあとのタイミングであればどこでも構いません。

Comment: 内部ストレージ直下のDownloadにはなにもファイルがなかったです。mediascannerは保存用メソッドを読んだ後に入れました。が、特に変わった様子はありませんでした。自分ではわからないのですが、そもそもコード自体がうまく書けていない可能性もあります。多分きちんとそのパスにファイルが生成できていないのかなと思いますので出直します。すみません。

Comment: 設定＞ストレージ＞外部メディア　からファイラーが使用可能です。こちらからの表示はMediaScan前でも表示可能なのでこちらでも見えなければファイル保存に失敗しているかと思います。また「ファイル保存できない」ならば別エントリで再質問頂いて、本質問はチェックマークを押下してください。